# Conditionally execute branch if variable is not undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piece of code and a variable sometimes comes as `undefined` but I need to validate if that value is `undefined` to pass the execution of code

the validation I provided is not solving the problem

```
   _getKeycodeScans = (data) => this.props.getKeycodeScans(data.keycode.uid, 1).then(() => {
        this.setState({detailsModalVisible: true, homeDetails: data});
    }).catch(error => {
        debugger
        const { serverError } = JSON.parse(error.message);
        this.setState({ serverError, loading: false });
    });

    _openDetailsModal = (data) => () => Promise.all([
        console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&**********&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'),
        console.log(data),

        this._getKeycodeScans(data),
        this._getKeycodeImageDataUrl(data),
        this._getHomes(data)
    ]);
```

When the _openDetailsModal gets hit and it calls the functions inside and the uid is undefined.
I get the error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined`.
When uid is undefined I actually don't need the data

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to only continue executing your script if `data.keycode.uid` is *not* undefined, you could just:

```
_getKeycodeScans = (data) => {
  if(!data.keycode || data.keycode.uid === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  return this.props.getKeycodeScans(data.keycode.uid, 1).then(() => {
    this.setState({detailsModalVisible: true, homeDetails: data});
  }).catch(error => {
    const { serverError } = JSON.parse(error.message);
    this.setState({ serverError, loading: false });
  });
}
```

Comment: it is returning a errorn _getKeycodeScans  is not a function